# eclipse builds wrong url when deploying to tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am learning Vaadin. I have a "HelloWorld" application and it is deploying to a tomcat server. The issue is when I run on the server inside Eclipse the URL is:

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/helloworld/HelloworldUI.java
```

I can go to the app using:

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/
```

What is the issue?